# Do I need Ajax or something to put different erb content in my tabs?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to have some tabs in an index page.
Each of the tabs should render a different category for the Food Model.

The tabs are working fine, but with static content.

**I have 2 tables:**

```
Foods, Categories
```

**And I have a column :category_id in my Foods table.**

My associations are: `Food has_one category, and Categories has_many foods.`

So, when clicking on one of the tabs, a category_id must be passed so that it knows what content to render.

I don't know how do I need to make my view (and maybe a scope?)...It's the first time I do this.

This is the code for one of the tabs:

```
<ul class="accordion-tabs">
  <li class="tab-header-and-content">
    <a href="#" class="is-active tab-link">Entrantes</a>
    <div class="tab-content row">
     <% @foods.by_category(params[1]).each do |food| %>
      <%= render "food_card" %>
     <% end %>
    </div>
  </li>
```

I'm trying to pass params manually in each of the tabs, but I don't know if I need AJAX or something. Please help!

#### Update

**My Foods Controller**

```
  def index
      @addictfood = Addictfood.last
      @food = Food.last
      @foods = Food.all
      @category = Category.find params[:id]
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json { render json: @category.foods.to_json }
      end
  end
```

**My index view (Foods)**

```
<ul class="accordion-tabs">
<div class="categories">
  <li class="tab-header-and-content">
   <% @categories.each do |tab| %>
      <%= link_to tab.name, category_show_path(tab), class: "tab-link" %>
   <% end %>
   </li>
</div>
</ul>
</article>

<script>
$(".categories").on("click", "a", function() {
   $.ajax({
       url: $(this).attr("href"),
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) {
           $(".category").html(data)
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

**Error**

```
Started GET "/foods" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-02 20:41:53 +0200
Processing by FoodsController#index as HTML
  Addictfood Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "addictfoods".* FROM "addictfoods" ORDER BY "addictfoods"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Food Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "foods".* FROM "foods" ORDER BY "foods"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Category without an ID):
  app/controllers/foods_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

Comment: `@category = Category.find params[:id]` will return only one item. Therefore, you can't iterate like `@categories.each do |tab|` . If you want to see all categories, then you need to change to `@categories = Category.all` . I'd suggest you to read this to help you understand better: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 2):

If each food has one category only you should use the belongs_to category association.

In Category, you can leave it with has_many foods.

In the **show view** of the category controller you can pull the food like this:

```
<% @category.foods.each do |food| %>
 <%= food.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ok till there, but now, how do I put in each tab the category id in order to pull the foods from that category without reloading?¿

Comment: sorry I forgot tagging you

Comment: you could pass the category id to a javascript function that will load the content into a div. example (using jquery): function loadFood(category_id) { $(".tab-content").load( "/category/"+category_id ); }

Answer (score 0):

**Params**

You won't be able to pass `params` to your tabs if they are within a single request. `Params` are sent via [HTTP in the URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), or behind the scenes, to give you variables in the backend of your app:

[image]

Params are there to give you the ability to manipulate the response after a request is made to the controller. In your case, with your files on the same page, you will need to use them in an ajax request to pull the relevant `category` content

--

**Ajax**

As mentioned by `@mavis`, you'll want to set up your models as such:

```
#app/models/food.rb
Class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :category
end

#app/models/category.rb
Class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :foods
end
```

This will give you the ability to list your tabs like this:

```
<div class="categories">
   <% @categories.each do |tab| %>
      <%= link_to tab.name, category_show_path(tab) %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

The problem you'll need to use `ajax` to overcome is to use it to populate your `tabs`, like this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(".categories").on("click", "a", function() {
   $.ajax({
       url: $(this).attr("href"),
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) {
           $(".category").html(data)
       }
   });
});
```

You'll then have to do this:

```
#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
Class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @category = Category.find params[:id]
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json { render json: @category.foods.to_json }
        end
    end 
end
```

Comment: thanks for responding. The thing is, I want the tabs to show up in Foods #index view. So, I would need to add the code you made for categories#show into my #index method? It keeps saying Couldn't find Category without an ID

Comment: Thanks for the reply! can you post your logs of the error?

Comment: Sure! Please check updated question , I've put all of the relevant stuff

Comment: By the way, the tabs are premade tabs from refills (Bourbon.io)

Comment: I almost have it...My only question is, how about the routes? What do I need to do with them?